# Parsing a Date / Time format with Apache Commons CSV `CSVFormat` class

Tags: java, csv, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am using [*Apache Commons CSV library.*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

I am trying to parse a date / time format to CSVFormat which leads to, if there is any time / date columns it will be formatted according to the format provided to CSVFormat.

When I remove date / time format it's working perfect, but it's NOT working when adding date / time format.

example of date / time formats I would like to add:

- YYYY-MM-DD
- DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:SS
- YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS

Also here is the code I am trying to add the date / time format to;

```
public ByteArrayInputStream dataToCSV(List<?> dataList, char delimiter){
        final CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(delimiter);
//        final String format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(delimiter).format("MM-YYYY-DD HH:mm:SS");
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(new PrintWriter(out), format);) {
            if (dataList.size() > 0){
                // headers will be written just one time
                csvPrinter.printRecord(this.getHeaders(dataList.get(0)));
                for (Object objectClass : dataList) {
                    List<String> data = getRecordData(objectClass);
                    csvPrinter.printRecord(data);
                }
            }
            csvPrinter.flush();
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

The line I commented is the one that not working. The first above one is the one that works properly.

Data is coming from a PostgreSQL DB, also I am using hibernate and commons-csv dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

example of timestamp field in DB

2022-11-23 11:12:13.123456

example of the same field formatted I got in CSV

2022-11-23 11:12:13.123456

example of needed format

11-23-2022 11:12:13.123456

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not knowing Apache CSVFormat, the way I read [the docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#format-java.lang.Object...-) you are supposed to pass the value(s) to be formatted to `format()`. Is that what you are doing? Is `"MM-YYYY-DD HH:mm:SS"` such a value? Also what error message are you seeing when you are adding date / time format?

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for your response!
```format()``` is a function that returns a String, but I need an CSVFormat Object to pass it to the ```CSVPrinter()``` 
So if I get it as ```String``` I can't add it as parameter to ```CSVPrinter()```

Also I added SS of the date / time field in DB as well as in CSV file, You can have a look  

Comment: This is confusing. Date formats really have nothing to do with `CSVFormat`. The function of that class appears to be to describe *metadata*. Your datetime values are *data*

Comment: The way I read the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html) a `CSVFormat` does not (cannot) provide a date format. If you need a particular date-time format in your resulting CSV, would it work to pass formatted strings to your `CSVPrinter`?

Comment: For how to handle date-time input in different formats, see for example [Format date in yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format from whatever format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708324/format-date-in-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-format-from-whatever-format) or [How to format date in java 8? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770698/how-to-format-date-in-java-8).

Comment: Well, I think it's not possible to bind it. Thank you guys for reply!

Comment: You might be better off using a library that *does* do binding such as OpenCsv. You would then be able to to adapt the binding to use your custom date parsing

Comment: @g00se thank you for recommendation, could you provide me more details about how openCsv deals with binding date / time formatting. Such as the function that binds, if there is an example of that function it will be so good. Again thanks for recommendations!

Comment: You would register a custom converter. Something like `public class LocalDateTimeConverter<LocalDate, Integer> extends AbstractBeanField<LocalDate, Integer>` where you'd insert the 'T' so that parsing went properly. See OpenCsv docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `CSVFormat#format` does *not* do what you think

Your call to `CSVFormat#format` in the commented line:

```
final String format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(delimiter).format("MM-YYYY-DD HH:mm:SS");
```

… is incorrect. And shows that you misunderstand how [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) works.

Unfortunately, the [Javadoc for that command](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#format-java.lang.Object...-) is nearly useless:

> Formats the specified values.

So let's look at [the source code](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/scm.html):

```java
1427    /**
1428     * Formats the specified values.
1429     *
1430     * @param values the values to format
1431     * @return the formatted values
1432     */
1433    public String format(final Object... values) {
1434        final StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
1435        try (CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(out, this)) {
1436            csvPrinter.printRecord(values);
1437            final String res = out.toString();
1438            final int len = recordSeparator != null ? res.length() - recordSeparator.length() : res.length();
1439            return res.substring(0, len);
1440        } catch (final IOException e) {
1441            // should not happen because a StringWriter does not do IO.
1442            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
1443        }
1444    }
```

We can see that you are supposed to pass *values*, not a date-time formatting pattern.

We can also see that this method does *not* write to your CSV file. Instead, this method is merely a shortcut for using `CSVPrinter` to generate the text of what would be written to your CSV file if your CSV file were the actual target of output. With this `format` method, the text generated is merely returned to the calling code.

You need to understand that Commons CSV does not do *binding*. The library merely parses pieces of CSV as plain text, not objects. So specifying a date-time formatting pattern with *Commons CSV* makes no sense; that's not a feature.

You must write your own Java code to produce the strings you want to send out to a CSV file through *Commons CSV*.

So you need to do the parsing from text to date-time object yourself. If you have a string such as `2022-11-23 00:00:00.0000`, you should be parsing as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object. To do so, you could define your own formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter` class. But instead I would do a bit of string manipulation to alter the input by [replacing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) the SPACE in the middle with a `T`:

```
LocalDateTime myLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-11-23 00:00:00.0000".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

To learn more about using *Apache Commons CSV*, search Stack Overflow. Many posts have already been made, including some authored by me.

### ISO 8601

Big Tip: Always use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for data exchange of date-time values. Quite easy to do with *java.time* classes as they use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
String output = myLocalDateTime.toString() ;
```

… and:

```
LocalDateTime myLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-11-23T00:00:00.0000" ) ;
```

See that [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/zfSAwk).

Another tip: If you are trying to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, always include an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. The `LocalDateTime` class cannot represent a moment as it lacks the context of an offset or zone.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response!
If I create a date-time formatter I'll for sure consider your two tips.